# Remover elemento de um ArrayList em Java

Tags: java

Estou com problemas para remover um elemento do meu ArrayList, alguém pode me ajudar como?

---

```
public String remover(Pessoa umaPessoa) {
        String mensagem = "\n******** Pessoa removida com Sucesso! ********\n";
        listaPessoas.remove(umaPessoa);
        return mensagem;
    }
```

---

```
else if (entradaTeclado.equalsIgnoreCase("remover")){

        System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa que você quer remover:");
        entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
        String umNome = entradaTeclado;

        //removendo uma pessoa na lista de pessoas do sistema
        Pessoa umaPessoa = new Pessoa(umNome);
        String mensagem = umControle.remover(umaPessoa);
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        }
```

Comment: A resposta que deveria ter sido marcada como correta é [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18873/357).

Comment: @Rafael, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você deve procurar o objeto que quer remover antes de removê-lo.
Quando você faz:

```
Pessoa umaPessoa = new Pessoa(umNome);
```

Você está criando um novo objeto que não está na lista e depois tenta removê-lo. Como ele não está na lista, não vai remover.

---

Você pode fazer assim:
Sendo `Pessoa` no mínimo algo como:

```
public class Pessoa 
{
    public Pessoa(String nome)
    {
        m_nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome()
    {
        return m_nome;
    }

    private String m_nome;
}
```

Você pode buscar e remover assim:

```
    ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();

    // Adiciona algumas pessoas.
    pessoas.add(new Pessoa("José"));
    pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Maria"));
    pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Pedro"));

    System.out.print("Pessoas cadastradas:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(pessoas.get(i).getNome() + "\n");
    }

    // Removendo Pedro:
    for(int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++)
    {
        Pessoa p = pessoas.get(i);

        if(p.getNome().equals("Pedro"))
        {
            // Encontrou uma pessoa cadastrada com nome "Pedro".

            // Remove.
            pessoas.remove(p);

            // Sai do loop.
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Pessoas cadastradas após remoção:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(pessoas.get(i).getNome() + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode manter o código do jeito que está, alterando apenas a classe `Pessoa`.
O problema, conforme citado, é que você está tentando remover um objeto que não é igual a nenhum outro na lista.

Você pode definir quando dois objetos são considerados iguais sobrescrevendo o método `equals(Object o)`.
Nesse caso, bastaria adicionar algo como o seguinte código na classe `Pessoa`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Pessoa outro) {
    if (this == outro) {
        return true;
    }
    if (outro == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return outro.m_pessoa == this.m_pessoa
        || (this.m_pessoa != null && this.m_pessoa.equals(outro.m_pessoa));
}
```

Leitura recomendada sobre uso de equals, hashCode e toString: http://altieresm.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/metodos-equals-hashcode-e-tostring/

Comment: Esta deveria ter sido marcada como a solução correta. Basta sobrescrever `equals()` e `hashCode()` na classe `Pessoa` que o método `ArrayList<Pessoa>.remove(Pessoa pessoa)` passa a funcionar para qualquer objeto `Pessoa` que contenha o mesmo nome que o objeto da lista que se deseja remover. A resposta que foi marcada como correta faz trabalho demais desnecessariamente e vai contra a API do Java.

Comment: @Leander, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que pode completar a sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você está fazendo

`Pessoa umaPessoa = new Pessoa(umNome)`

O novo objeto Pessoa criado não é o mesmo objeto que contem no array. Uma solução simples seria você pegar o objeto `Pessoa` do ArrayList que tem o mesmo nome de `umNome` e mandar o objeto retornado para o método remover.

Comment: @elipemm, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa te ajudar a entender melhor a pergunta do Rafael.

Answer (score 0):

Usando enhanced for, supondo que this.alunos seja um ArrayList, e que Aluno tenha getters propiamente feitos:

```
public boolean removeAluno(String name) {
    for(Aluno a:this.alunos) {
        if(a.getName().equals(name))
        this.alunos.remove(a);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```