# Erro ao remover item do ArrayList

Tags: java, android, array

Estou "brincando" com o canvas (android) e estou com problema ao remover elemento de um ArrayList.

O app funciona assim: O usuário clica na tela, aparece uma bolinha que vai subindo mas eu quero remover apenas as bolinhas que ultrapassaram o limite de `y <= -50`. Quando eu vou remover ele gera esse erro:

```
09-08 23:28:12.617: E/AndroidRuntime(6719):  FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2330
09-08 23:28:12.617: E/AndroidRuntime(6719):  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
09-08 23:28:12.617: E/AndroidRuntime(6719):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-08 23:28:12.617: E/AndroidRuntime(6719):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-08 23:28:12.617: E/AndroidRuntime(6719):  at com.dotjogoqualquer.JogoView.update(JogoView.java:50)
09-08 23:28:12.617: E/AndroidRuntime(6719):  at com.dotjogoqualquer.JogoView.run(JogoView.java:40)
09-08 23:28:12.617: E/AndroidRuntime(6719):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Código

```
public void update() {
                if (obj.size() >= 1){
                        for(int x = 0; x < obj.size(); x++) {
                                obj.get(x).y -= 15;
                                if (obj.get(x).y < -50) {
                                        obj.remove(x); //Erro ocorre aqui
                                }
                        }
                }
                postInvalidate();
        }
```

Links do código completo
http://pastebin.com/hDz3nyzk (Linha 48)

Comment: E se vc tentar usar o objeto e não o index para executar a remoção?, como neste [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11882/remover-elemento-de-um-arraylist-em-java)

Comment: tipo assim ó....

    public void update() {
      if (obj.size() >= 1){
        for(int x = 0; x < obj.size(); x++) {
          obj.get(x).y -= 15;
          if (obj.get(x).y < -50) {
            obj.remove(obj.get(x));                   // <<<=================== AQUI
          }
        }
      }
      postInvalidate();
    }

Comment: tentei isso que seria o mais correto (eu acho) `for(objetos _x : obj) {
    _x.y -= 15;
    if (_x.y < -50) {
     obj.remove(_x);
    }
   }` resultou neste erro http://pastebin.com/QCLP0ipJ

Comment: viche, agora vc está removendo o item, mas ao mesmo tempo tem gente adicionando, quem sabe se vc utilizar [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro acontece porque você está removendo os itens da lista de dentro de um for, isso acontece porque quando o *for* foi "montado" pela VM a lista tinha um tamanho X, você retirou alguns itens, logo quando chamar lista.get(x) e x for maior que o número de itens da lista uma exceção será lançada.

Em um FOR as suas duas primeiras partes (a de declaração de variáveis e a de condição de parada) são chamadas apenas uma vez.

Suponhamos que a sua lista tenha 10 itens, logo a chamada de `obj.size()` retornará 10, como a condição de parada é `x < 10` o loop será executado independentemente se foi retirado ou adicionado itens na lista.
Vamos imaginar que a lista tem 10 itens:

```
 for(int x = 0; x < obj.size(); x++) { // Aqui foi definido que o loop vai até X == 9

      // Se um item for removido, vai dar erro AQUI 
      // na ultima iteração do loop, pois o tamanho da lista será 8 e x será 9
      obj.get(x).y -= 15; 

      if (obj.get(x).y < -50) { //Se nenhum item for removido não vai dar erro

          obj.remove(x); 
      }
 }
```

Além disso existem formas mais elegantes de fazer a mesma coisa, se você estiver usando Java 7 pode utilizar as classes utilitárias do [Guava](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) para aplicar a sua lógica. Utilizando o Guava ficaria assim:

```
     List<TipoDeDados> listaTransformada = Lists.transform(lista, new Function<TipoDeDados, TipoDeDados>() {

        @Override
        public TipoDeDados apply(TipoDeDados input) {
            input.y -= 15;
            return input;
        }
    });

    Iterables.removeIf(listaTransformada, new Predicate<TipoDeDados>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(TipoDeDados input) {
            return input.y < -50;
        }
    });
```

O bom da da utilização das classes Function e Predicate é que você pode dar um nome descritivo para as implementações o que torna mais fácil de compreender o algorítimo.

Já se você estiver utilizando a versão 8 do Java, é mais simples ainda, basta utilizar os métodos da própria interface List, ficando assim:

```
    lista.forEach( tipoDeDado -> tipoDeDado.y -= 15);

    lista.removeIf( tipoDeDado -> tipoDeDado.y < -50 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Há mais de uma thread mexendo com a lista ao mesmo tempo? Tente cercar todos os trechos de código que lidam com esta lista com

synchronized (obj) { 
    ...
}

Todo o corpo do método da pergunta deve estar protegido desta forma. A propósito, verificar se o size() >= 1 é desnecessário porque o loop não faz nada se a lista não tiver nenhum elemento.